# CanvasJS unable to change x axis format on stacked area chart

Tags: canvasjs

I have a CanvasJS stacked area chart which is ignoring my attempts to change the x axis labels font size and color.  I use this code:

```
axisX: {   
gridThickness: 0,
interval: 5,
lineThickness: 1,
labelFontColor: "#000000",
labelFontSize:12
```

but my  axis labels remain unchanged from the default size and color:
[image]

is there anything special required for stacked area charts?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to be working fine at our end. Can you kindly create a jsfiddle reproducing the issue?  https://image.prntscr.com/image/vicmQs6zSNCc-Y85bN0tmQ.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that the axis format property was not inside the x axis jason node, so user error!  Thanks for the reply Indranil.